# Undefined method each Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

The run down.  A person can have many bids, this particular person only has one bid.

In my index action I have `@bids = Bid.find_by_person_id(params[:person_id])`

in my view I do

```
<% @bids.each do |bid| %>
   <%= bid.bid_amount %>
<% end %>
```

I am getting `NoMethodError: undefined method each' for #<Bid:0x007f988a346f00>` when visting the index view for person bids.

Is this because this person only has one bid?  I feel thats not the case, but other than that im at a loss..

Comment: I know that it is not nil though.  I debugged to verify.

Comment: you cannot iterate over a single record my friend

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`find_by` returns the first item.  I think you are looking for

```
Bid.where(person_id: params[:person_id])
```

Answer (score 2):

`Austio`'s answer is correct.

However, why are you calling the `Bid` model directly?...

> A person can have many bids

You're obviously constructing data from the *person* model, so why not call the following:

```
@person = Person.find params[:person_id]
@bids = @person.bids #-> bids belong to @person
```

This will build the collection without calling `where`.

Of course, your method only uses a single db query. But even still, the above is much more intuitive.

--

As an aside, you'll also want to use a conditional before your loop:

```
<% if @bids.any? %>
   <% @bids.each.... %>
<% end %>
```

Having *one* bid is fine, but having *none* will cause the loop to spit out an error. The above resolves that issue.

Comment: This is not true: "Having one bid is fine, but having none will cause the loop to spit out an error." Calling `each` on an empty collection will not spit out an error.

Comment: Does for me whenever I've called it on an empty collection.

Comment: No it doesn't. Assume: `@bids = Bid.where(:id => [non-existing-id])` then this does not throw any errors: `@bids.each{|bid| ... }`.

Comment: Hmmm let me test this out.

Comment: You can also just try with an empty array. Basically the same.

Comment: Firing up IRB, let me see about this